# array and checkboxes, I want boxes to checked/unchecked based on array values and also update array when someone check any box and update the form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Array:**

```
0: {scat_id: '1', scat_name: 'Domain Knowledge', scat_identifier: 'domain knowledge', sname_id: '2', sname_cat_id: '1', …}
1: {scat_id: '1', scat_name: 'Domain Knowledge', scat_identifier: 'domain knowledge', sname_id: '4', sname_cat_id: '1', …}
5: {scat_id: '2', scat_name: 'Type of Testing', scat_identifier: 'type-of-testing', sname_id: '8', sname_cat_id: '2', …}
6: {scat_id: '2', scat_name: 'Type of Testing', scat_identifier: 'type-of-testing', sname_id: '23', sname_cat_id: '2', …}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="bfsi" ng-model="skill_set.bfsi" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="ecommerce" ng-model="skill_set.ecommerce" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="api" ng-model="skill_set.api" value="26">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="game" ng-model="skill_set.game" value="23">
```

Comment: Have you written any code for this yet?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name=NAME OF THE CHECKBOXES]");
let enabledCatFilters = []     
 checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
                checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
                    enabledCatFilters =
                        Array.from(checkboxes) // Convert checkboxes to an array to use filter and map.
                            .filter(i => i.checked) // Use Array.filter to remove unchecked checkboxes.
                            .map(i => parseInt(i.value)) // Use Array.map to extract only the checkbox values from the array of objects.
               alert(enabledCatFilters);
            })
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).